# How to analyze c# project with sonarqube LTS 6.7 and sonar runner?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We are facing problem while analyzing c# project that how to set environmental variable and how to execute sonar runner command?

Comment: please let me know if anyone having idea about same??

Comment: Please, give more details about your problem. Did you read the documentation of Sonar Scanner for MSBuild? https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

Comment: From the root folder of the project how we can analyze, execute the following commands:

SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end

Comment: Now C# Project is anlayzed successfully but even if threre is issue then on sonar dashboard it shows zero issues? why?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the Scanner for MSBuild from the root dir of your project you need to do one of the following:

- add the folder where the Scanner for MSBuild is installed to the system PATH variable. You could follow the instructions in this answer (see "Old Method"): https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10
- type the full name of the executables, for example if you installed Scanner for MSBuild into `c:\tools\sonar-scanner-msbuild.4.0` the commands could be:

`c:\tools\sonar-scanner-msbuild.4.0\sonarqube.scanner.msbuild.exe ...
msbuild ...
c:\tools\sonar-scanner-msbuild.4.0\sonarqube.scanner.msbuild.exe ...`